# .after() is omitting some children divs

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm using `.after()` method to inject some html code, I'm doing it inside a loop, everything was working fine. Then I added a `div` parent to some divs and for some reason the children of those container divs are missing.

```
const setContent = (sections) => {
  let contentElements = sections.map(section => `
    <div id="${section.key}_section" class="anchor-tag section-tag">
      <div id="${section.key}_section_content">
        <div class="subsection-group">
          <div id="${section.key}_first_parent_div">
            <div id="${section.key}_first_child_div"></div>
            <div id="${section.key}_second_child_div"></div>
          </div>
          <div id="${section.key}_second_parent_div">
            <div id="${section.key}_first_child_div"></div>
            <div id="${section.key}_second_child_div"></div>
          </div>
          <div id="${section.key}_outer_alone_child"></div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div id="${section.key}_other_uncle"></div>
          <div id="${section.key}_other_aunt"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  `).join("");
  $('#div_before').after(`${contentElements}`);
};
setContent(sectionsArr);
```

If I `console.log(contentElements)` everything is there, but for some reason after mouting the elements, both `_first_child_div` and `_second_child_div` are missing. All sections (divs `id="${section.key}_section`) that have lost child start with  `style="display: none;"`, I don't know how to debug it, and I couldn't find anything on `.after()` api that could relate to that issue

Comment: What is `#div_before`?

Comment: `<span></span>
<div class="root-div">
  <div id="div_before" class="top-menu-div"></div>
</div>` It's the first child of the main page `div`

Comment: You have duplicate IDs. You have `_first_child_div` and `_second_child_div` in both `_first_parent_div` and `_second_parent_div`. That's invalid, although I don't think it would cause this problem.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: You could output the `contentElements` to Console for debugging. Can you provide an example of `sections`?

Comment: I agree with Twisty that the first step in debugging this should be to look at exactly what you are getting in `contentElements`, before you do any JQuery actions with it. It's possible that this has nothing to do with `after()` in particular. And if that looks like what you expected, then the second step would be to fix the duplicate ID issue Barmar mentioned; it would not cause a browser to remove any elements, but what it would cause JQuery to do is (I think) undefined.

Comment: after a little more debuug I found out, there as a method getting all divs with a specific class and calling an `.empty()` this was wiping the children